# Java: How do I catalog Java API documents using Quicksilver?

Tags: java, macos, quicksilver

This one is for Java programmers on Mac.

How do I catalog Java API documents using [Quicksilver](http://blacktree.com/?quicksilver)? Wouldn't it be nice if you could lookup API documents with a few key strokes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Download Java API document locally](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp).

Then follow the instructions in [Indexing Java SDK Docs with QuickSilver](http://www.entropy.ch/blog/Developer/?permalink=Indexing-Java-SDK-Docs-with-QuickSilver.html).

> [Add] the “allclasses-frame.html” file
>   into a new [“J2SE”] group in the
>   catalog and set the “Include Contents”
>   option to “HTML Links”. QuickSilver
>   will parse the HTML file and since the
>   file contains a long list of links to
>   all the class pages, the result in the
>   index is exactly what I want. As you
>   can see in the screenshot, it picks up
>   about 3200 classes.
>   [image]
>   <sub>(source: [entropy.ch](http://www.entropy.ch/images/blog/2006-09-27-quicksilver-catalog.png))</sub>